# How can I reload a running Ruby file?

Tags: ruby

How can I reload a running Ruby file (on `KILL -HUP pid`) so that code changes are recognised?

Answer (score 0):

There is built-in way to reload an already interpreted file.

I mean, you can re-evaluate the file itself using `load('/path/to/file')`, but that will just override what Ruby already have in memory without removing already defined methods or classes. That can cause several unexpected side effects.

Some libraries get around the issue by running the code in a subprocess or thread. Others, such as Ruby, deletes the defined objects and reloads the file. You can check the code for [`reload!`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/ConsoleMethods.html#method-i-reload-21) if you are interested in learning one possible approach.

However, the best solution is to stop and restart the entire process.